# How to avoid marginal notes in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, marginnote

**Short Version**
I want to stop marginal notes from being copied to the TOC

**Long Version**

I use LyX to write notes in class.

When a lesson starts, I mention the date of the lesson in a marginal note; This often happens when a section or subsection starts, so I have a line which looks something like this:
17/04/15      4.7      The Vestibulo-Ocular Reflex

This is very nice IMHO, and I would like to keep it like this. However, when I add a table of contents in the beginning of the summary, the marginal note appears in the TOC as well - which makes the TOC page messy and full of strange dates on the side.

Is there a way to avoid this? Preferably just a way to tell LaTeX not to copy marginal notes to the TOC..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: Insert -> Short Title just before the Chapter heading and use the Chapter title. The Short Title is used in the TOC. See LyX UserGuide section 3.3.4.4 under Help.

Comment: This is a bit cumbersome but it seems to work, so I might use it if there's nothing simpler to do. Thanks.